# android gps coordinate comparasion

Tags: android, gps

i'm developing android app that will inform the user where is he (in which building), gps work fine but it's not accurate that why i'm using range in my code because the building is very near to each other ,but it is not efficient to use many of IF ELSE in 34 building. 
is there any other way?

here is my code.
package com.example.gps;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button btnShowLocation;

// GPSTracker class
GPSTracker gps,gps2;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);

    // show location button click event
    btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {        
            // create class object
            gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);

            // check if GPS enabled     
            if(gps.canGetLocation()){


                double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                if((latitude >=21.4886 && latitude <=21.4893)&& (longitude >=39.2454 && longitude <=39.2459))
                // \n is for new line
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your are in  building 7 " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                else
                    if((latitude >=21.48899 && latitude <=21.4899)&& (longitude >=39.2456 && longitude <=39.2459))

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your are in  building 8 " , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    //} 
            }else{
                // can't get location
                // GPS or Network is not enabled
                // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                gps.showSettingsAlert();
            }

        }
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use locationManager and LocationListener

Answer (score 0):

You can use minumum distance ***algorithm***

[link](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-minimum-distance-between-two-numbers/)